# How would I be able to tell if some vector is in the span of a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, vector-spaces

Given the following, how would I be able to tell if **b** and **c** are in the span of the set of vectors *S*? Any help is appreciated.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6kgg.png)

Comment: I think that you would benifit from a [MathJaX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141). It would really help you to format your questions nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that S contains two linearly independent vectors(first two). Now express b and c as a linear combination of the two linearly independent vectors.Now try to solve these  equation.If you can solve these equation then you can say b,c belongs to span of S,otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Form a matrix with its rows the given vectors, and reduce. Iff you get a row of only zeros is that vector in the span of the other ones:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\\
3&1&3\\
\!\!-3&\!\!-9&\!\!-6\\
7&5&8\\
15&13&18\\
1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\\
0&\!\!-8&\!\!-3\\
0&0&0\\
0&\!\!-16&\!\!-6\\
0&\!\!-32&\!\!-12\\
0&\!\!-2&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\\
0&\!\!-8&\!\!-3\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&\!\!-\frac14\end{pmatrix}$$

The above means: the original vector space spanned by those four vectors is *in fact* spanned only by the first two, and of the other two vectors given the first one belongs to this space, the second one doesn't.